# Does BehaviorSubject somehow interfere with Angular2 *ngFor?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ionic-framework

In my Component I have a public property that is a class of Medication, and that has a property within it that is an array of a different class Time. (I'm trying to allow specifying different times that this medication is taken)

When I click a button I push a new item into the array, but the `*ngFor` in my template doesn't update to reflect the larger array.

Here's a plnkr that works correctly: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y9ywQyOABzC5BJ2LQvkJ?p=preview

**The plnkr equivilant of addmedication.ts**

```
//our root app component
import {ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

export class Time {
    id: number;
    interval: string;
    times?: Array<string>;
    days?: Array<string>;
    useInterval: boolean;
    constructor(id: number, interval: string, times: Array<string>, days: Array<string>) {
        this.id = id;
        this.interval = interval;
        this.times = times || [];
        this.days = days || [];
        if (this.interval) {
            this.useInterval = true;
        }
    }
}

export class Medication {
  times?: Array<Time>;
  constructor() {
    this.times = Array<Time>();
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'addmedication.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class App {
  public medication: Medication;
  constructor() {
    this.medication = new Medication();
  }
  additem() {
    this.medication.times.push(new Time(undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined));
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**addmedication.html**

```
<div>
      <h2>Click below</h2>
      <button (click)="additem()">Click me and something should happen below</button>
    <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let time of medication.times">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <label>Taken every...</label>
                <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="time.useInterval" name="useInterval" />
              </li>
              <li *ngIf="time.useInterval">
                <label>Interval</label>
                <select [(ngModel)]="time.interval" name="interval">
                  <option>Every First</option>
                  <option>Every Second</option>
                  <option>Every Third</option>
                  <option>Every Fourth</option>
                  <option>First</option>
                  <option>Last</option>
                </select>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>Day of Week</label>
                <select [(ngModel)]="time.days" name="days" multiple="true">
                  <option>Sunday</option>
                  <option>Monday</option>
                  <option>Tuesday</option>
                  <option>Wednesday</option>
                  <option>Thursday</option>
                  <option>Friday</option>
                  <option>Saturday</option>
                </select>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>Time of Day</label>
                <select [(ngModel)]="time.times" name="times" multiple="true">
                  <option>Morning</option>
                  <option>Afternoon</option>
                  <option>Evening</option>
                  <option>Bedtime</option>
                </select>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div>
      But why can't I add a <b>Time</b> to <b>medication.times</b> in the file below and have the <b>*ngFor</b> pick it up?
      <a href="https://github.com/wadewadewadewadewadewade/ineffectua/blob/master/src/pages/medications/addmedication.ts" target="_blank">github -> addmedication.ts</a>
      <a href="https://github.com/wadewadewadewadewadewade/ineffectua/blob/master/src/pages/medications/addmedication.html" target="_blank">github -> addmedication.html</a>
      </div>
        </div>
```

But the files in my Ionic project do not seem to work like the plnkr version does. When I run my project as 'ionic serve' I see the array get an item added to it in the console output, but it never appears visually in the page.

- https://github.com/wadewadewadewadewadewade/ineffectua/blob/master/src/pages/medications/addmedication.ts
- https://github.com/wadewadewadewadewadewade/ineffectua/blob/master/src/pages/medications/addmedication.html

I have some hunches: maybe the version of Angular in my project is buggy, it could be that I am missing including some directive in my app somewhere, perhaps the immutable BehaviorSubject from some other page is altering this page; stuff like that, but I am still new to Angular so your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can't find `BehaviorSubject` in your code.

Comment: Ya, I probably should have added more detail there. BehaviorSubject is used in the page that opens this Modal. I load the medications into a BehaviorSubject<List<Medication>> in medications.ts (via the constructor) here, and one hunch is that is why my local project doesn't work but the plnkr does...https://github.com/wadewadewadewadewadewade/ineffectua/blob/master/src/pages/medications/medications.ts Can a parent Observable or Immutable override changes a child makes within a modal?

Comment: Doesn't sound likely but I have no idea why it wouldn't work.

Comment: It seemed unlikely to me as well, but I'm still pretty "green around the gills" so to speak regarding Angular. Observables are still a bit of black-box to me. They're neat so far tho!

Comment: There is no observable involved with anything related to the `*ngFor` in your question.

Comment: I am guessing it has something to do with your use of `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. It's new to me, but from what I read sounds like it could be your culprit.

Comment: I tried removing the OnPush part of my Component before posting this question, but that didn't help. Also, OnPush is in my plnkr and works there. And the Observable and Immutable elements are part of the github project I referenced (that doesnt' work), not the plnkr (which works), as I didn't think replicating the entire project in plnkr was necessary, with it's API calls to a backend.

Comment: You mentioned that your project using ionic. try to export the small part of the app store with BehaviorSubject subject and component to a standard angular-cli project and try it there. BehaviorSubject with ngFor is very standard combination that should work.

Comment: Also u said "large array". does it update the small array?

Comment: I have a MedicationStore that uses a BehaviorSubject<List<Medication>> and that seems to work to maintain a list of medications. It goes back to the dataservice to when i add, so I bet some subscribe causes the *ngFor there to work. The Array<Time> is a property on Medication, and it's that Array that I can't seem to modify and get to appear in the page. I'm just trying to add a Time to the array without a server round trip, then save the data back to the API when data is finalized. Hopefully that clarifies my intentions a bit.

Comment: You mentioned running from an angular-cli without using Ionic. That's an interesting idea! Is there some resource you've used in the past you might point me at to give me some ideas on how to do that on my machine? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. Like most coding problems, it was something obvious.

The ion-labels I was using in my list were hiding the ion-items that *ngFor was creating. Yup, I'm that dumb. As Julia suggested, this was an Ionic issue (well, my issue not seeing what Ionic was doing) and not an Angular issue.

I haven't figured out why ion-label in a nested ion-list in Ionic 2 are hiding the entire nested list yet. But that's what is happening.

Thanks for your help!